# How to get return POST API in Flutter

Tags: api, post, authentication, dart, flutter

I need your help. I've been follow tutorial for POST API from [Login App using REST API and SQFLite](https://medium.com/@kashifmin/flutter-login-app-using-rest-api-and-sqflite-b4815aed2149) , but I can't have any return after calling the request. Please correct my code below.

login_presenter.dart

```
doLogin(String username, String password) {
api.callAPI(username, password).then((Post user) {
  _view.onLoginSuccess(user);
}).catchError((Exception error) => _view.onLoginError(error.toString()));}
```

rest_ds.dart

```
Future<User> login(String username, String password) {
return _netUtil.post(LOGIN_URL, body: {
  "username": username,
  "password": password
}).then((dynamic res) {
  print(res.toString());
  if(res["error"]) throw new Exception(res["error_msg"]);
  return new User.map(res["user"]);
});
```

}

second tutorial I'd get from [ParsingJSON-Flutter](https://github.com/PoojaB26/ParsingJSON-Flutter) , the error **Object.noSuchMethod** always point at `_presenter.doLogin(_username, _password);` which mean I don't reach the presenter? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should parse the JSON from response.body not the body directly.

```
Future<User> login(String username, String password) {
return _netUtil.post(LOGIN_URL, body: {
  "username": username,
  "password": password
}).then((response) {
      //check response status, if response status OK
      print("Response Status : $res");
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        var data = json.decode(response.body);

        if(data.length>0){
          //Convert your JSON to Model here
        }
        else{
          //Get Your ERROR message's here
          var errorMessage = data["error_msg"];
        }
      }
});
```

Comment: please add some context to your answer